# Counting SFTP files matching certain criteria using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I have a working program that deletes log files from a remote server (based on a certain pattern). Now when I want to get the count of files that match my criteria I am getting problems. It turns I cannot directly get the count from the `SftpFile` file object. I can only get the count of the files after setting a breakpoint.

I am able to delete the files using :

```
private void ListDirectory(SftpClient client, String dirName)
{
    var fileext = ".log";
    var fileextension = fileext.ToString();

    foreach (SftpFile file in client.ListDirectory(dirName))
    {
        var logFilePath = file.FullName;
        var fileCount = client.ListDirectory(dirName).GetEnumerator();

        if ((file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != "..") && file.Name.EndsWith(fileextension))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
            client.Delete(logFilePath);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I do set a breakpoint I can get the count from a nested object of this line:

```
var fileCount = client.ListDirectory(dirName).GetEnumerator();
```

I have a snapshot of the debug:

[image]

Now I need a way to directly access the count of files for my pattern i.e this line:

```
if ((file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != "..") && file.Name.EndsWith(fileextension))
```

When I  try to apply some Linq as below:

```
 var fileCount = client.ListDirectory(dirName).Where((file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != "..") && file.Name.EndsWith(fileextension)).Count();
```

I get further exception saying

> Cannot convert from 'bool' to 'system.func

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you have in `Where` method argument is not a valid lambda function, you miss the parameter list. It should be:

```
.Where(file => (file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != "..") && file.Name.EndsWith(fileextension))
```

---

Also, do not call `ListDirectory` repeatedly, let alone in every iteration.

```
var files = client.ListDirectory(dirName);
files =
    files.Where(
        file => (file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != "..") &&
        file.Name.EndsWith(fileextension));

int count = files.Count();
foreach (SftpFile file in files)
{
    // ...
}
```